# How to disable User Management for Administrator in Window 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, user-accounts, administrator

I have two admins accounts A and B in Window 7. I want to disable User Management for B admin account.

My approach that I took was

1. I hide the User Management options from control Panel for B from A using Group Poliy. But the problem is hiding does not mean deactivating.
2. Even with Command Prompt you can manage users using net user command. So, I deleted net.exe from system32 folder.

So, my approach should work, until and unless the admin B figured it out that I deleted the net.exe file and downloaded this file from internet or just copy from another window 7 computer and paste on this computer.

So, Is there any way I could disable User Management for B admin account from A admin account or any possible way?

One thing was making the User Account B a standard user instead of Administrator but the problem is Account B should have admin right to perform other tasks. Like Install and uninstall software or do backup and so on.

Comment: You cant really have admins which you do not trust. There way way too many functions they can use to circumvent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is nearly impossible.
Every block you can put on him he can bypass, if he's knowledgeable enough and has physical access (no need to be even an admin...).

Anyway, I think you're better figuring out how to give him the exact rights he needs.

If that's not an option, than you can try one of the following:

1. Create a whitelist Software restriction policy (through gpedit.msc) that blocks all applications except the ones you approve.
2. A bit of long shot, but maybe removing the rights from the SAM file (C:\Windows\System32\Config\SAM) would prevent him from managing it.

Please note that, unless in a domain, local group policies applies to all users.

One last thing, what's your main problem in this situation? you want to block him from creating new users? resetting your password?

Comment: First the computer is not in a domain, Second it is not a problem when the local group policies applies to all users. I just want to disable admin B to create a new user account and change the password. One more thing, Do you have any tutorial where it is explained the points that you have given above?

Comment: Software restriction policy is quite straight forward, but here's one: http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/securing+windows+server+2003/Chapter+6.+Running+Secure+Code/6.3+Software+Restriction+Policies/ and here's one for the file permissions: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7